# Spooling speed from SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a table with 70000 rows
MYPROMPT  varchar2(100),
Mystring1 varchar2(100),
Mystring2 varchar2(100)

So, data might look like this:

```
 'GREETING','Hello there','Joe' 
 'GREETING','Hello there','Mike'
 'GREETING','Hi','Steve' 
 'FIRING','You are fired','Dave'
 'FIRING','Outta here','Bob'
```

I need to spool this to a file like

```
GREETING
Hello there Joe
Hello there Mike
Hi Steve
FIRING
You are fired Dave
Outta here Bob
```

I have a script that handles this, doing a select for each MYPROMPT, and this works fine.  It runs a series of queries based on the various values for MYPROMPT.
The problem is that it takes a long time to spool to the output file I need (well over an hour).
Is there something I can set, either in SQLPlus or at the database that will speed this up?

Comment: When you're spooling the data to a file, you can SET TERMOUT OFF, this will be much faster as it doesn't have to spend the time to write it to the screen,or you can have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560398/oracle-sql-plus-spool

Comment: THanks much!  TERMOUT has helped markedly and I'll check out the other advice as well.

Comment: Sadly, none of this helped.  BUT, its possible there's more of a system issue at the moment.  Working on that now.

Comment: You mention multiple queries. What are they? If could easily be that they are slowing you  down.

Comment: @Ben, actually, everything is running slow on that database (it takes me several seconds just to sort 70k records).  So I don't think I can point fingers until I get that resolved.

Comment: You do have indexes right? People would be more able to help you if you posted the relevant parts of your table creation script, your queries and their explain plans.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  My point was I do not need any more help because it is actually NOT the problem I thought it was.  My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.  It wasn't SQLPlus causing the problem, but rather a problem with my query.